# How to make Home key ALWAYS go to beginning of line ONLY and NEVER go to beginning of textarea field in Chrome (EVEN when cursor is on blank line)?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromium

Until quite recently (I think <1 year ago), the behavior of the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys while editing a `textarea` field in Chromium/Chrome was identical to the behavior I have come to expect from decades of computer use — the same behavior that these keys *still* exhibit in all *other* apps on my system, including:

- Firefox while editing a `textarea`
- Gedit text editor

But one day (presumably after updating Chromium on my system), this behavior suddenly changed.

Why/how/when (in which version and which commit) did this change, and more importantly how do I get the original/standard/sane behavior of <kbd>Home</kbd> back?

Note: I tested this on Chrome on Windows and the problem was not present there, so this bug seems to be limited to Chromium/Chrome on Linux *only*, for some reason.

### My test case

To test/reproduce the behavior of <kbd>Home</kbd> inside a `textarea` field, go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea and type or paste the following contents into the text field:

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
```

### The original/sane/expected behavior

When I press <kbd>Home</kbd>, the cursor should move to the beginning of the line. Always. Nothing else. If it's *already* at the beginning of a line (including a blank line), then it should not move anywhere.

Example: When cursor is at the beginning of a blank line (indicated by the `|` here):

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
|
Paragraph 3
```

, pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> should not cause the cursor to move at all, and it should remain here:

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
|
Paragraph 3
```

### The new/broken/unwanted behavior

When the cursor is at the end, middle, or anywhere but the beginning of a line, <kbd>Home</kbd> works as expected.

When the cursor is at the beginning of a *non-blank* line, <kbd>Home</kbd> works as expected.

But when the cursor is at the beginning of a *blank* line (indicated by the `|` here):

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
|
Paragraph 3
```

, pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the *field* instead of the beginning of the *line*, like so:

```
|Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragraph 3
```

(Pressing <kbd>End</kbd> in this case is *also* broken, but at least much less dramatically: it only causes the cursor to move down to the next line, the same as if I had pressed <kbd>↓ Down</kbd>.)

The new behavior acts as if I had pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> — which of course is what I *would* have pressed if I had *wanted* to move the text cursor to the beginning of the *field* — but I *only* asked to move to the beginning of the line, thank you please.

It seems bizarre to me that the behavior of any key would be conditional depending on your position within the buffer / which character happens to be the right of your current insertion point (`\n`). That would be like making <kbd>← Left</kbd> work so that if your cursor is positioned right before a space, that it acts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>← Left</kbd> and moves left by one word, while otherwise only moves left by one character.

For the most part, I've managed to work around this bizarre bug so far. But the mystery and bizarreness of the unexpected change stil irks me.

And from time to time it still trips me up when I'm editing some large post containing many paragraphs (on GitLab, StackExchange, etc.). One accidental press of <kbd>Home</kbd> in the "wrong" place and it sends me clear up to the top of the field and makes me lose my place, which is quite aggravating as it can take quite a while to get back to where I was again and regain my train of thought.

### Why do I press <kbd>Home</kbd> if I'm already at the beginning of a line?

Well, that's beside the point, but a fair question, I suppose.

One case where this happens is if I'm trying to systematically add a prefix to the beginning of every line in a range of lines.  When editing a Markdown comment, I may want to quote some lines, so I'll add `>` to the beginning of each line, or I may want to indent a block of text so that it becomes part of a list item, so I'll add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line.

To do that efficiently in a browser (and not in `vim` where I'd rather be editing the text) requires repeatedly pressing a sequence of keys such as <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>↓ Down</kbd>. This simple no-thought-required process no longer works if you have to cautiously pause and think about "where" you are everytime you're about to press <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Comment: Issue is seen on latest version of Vivaldi , it is not seen on old version of Edge ! I too like the "old behaviour" , the "new behaviour" is not intuitive !